# How to link native libraries to Gradle

Tags: android, c++, gradle, sdl

I am trying to build an android version of my program written in C/C++ and SDL2 library, according to [this](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/main/docs/README-android.md) link.

using this command I created the gradle project:

```
./androidbuild.sh org.libsdl.testgles ../test/testgles.c
```

and according to tutorial I needed to build the project using this command:

```
./gradlew installDebug
```

But the gradle build task fails and it throws me this Error:

```
home/yolo/Workstation/Android/SDL/build/com.yolo.test/app/jni/src/main.cpp:2:10: fatal error: 'SDL2/SDL.h' file not found   
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>   
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~   
1 error generated.  
make: *** [/home/yolo/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529/build/core/build-binary.mk:478: /home/yolo/Workstation/Android/SDL/build/com.yolo.test/app/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/5d2wq3g4/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/main/main.o] Error 1

Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.BuildCommandException: Build command failed.  
Error while executing process /home/yolo/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529/ndk-build with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=/home/yolo/Workstation/Android/SDL/build/com.yolo.test/app/jni/Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=/home/yolo/Workstation/Android/SDL/build/com.yolo.test/app/jni/Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=1 NDK_OUT=/home/yolo/Workstation/Android/SDL/build/com.yolo.test/app/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/5d2wq3g4/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=/home/yolo/Workstation/Android/SDL/build/com.yolo.test/app/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/5d2wq3g4/lib APP_PLATFORM=android-16 SDL2 main}  
make: Nothing to be done for 'SDL2'.    
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: main <= main.cpp
```

It looks like that Gradle is not linked to SDL libraries therefore it thinks they are not installed.

You can see the full scan [here](https://scans.gradle.com/s/bgydgethopaxq/failure?expanded-stacktrace=WyIwIl0#1).

**UPDATE**

This is the content of /app/jni/src/Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := main

SDL_PATH := ../SDL

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(SDL_PATH)/include

# Add your application source files here...
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=  main.cpp

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := SDL2

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lGLESv1_CM -lGLESv2 -lOpenSLES -llog -landroid

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Have you looked at the makefile (`/app/jni/src/Android.mk` I think) to see how it is supposed to find the SDL header files? At least post the relevant content of that file here.

Comment: @john I looked at it right now and it's contents are ```include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)``` can you explain what it means?

Comment: I think you might be looking at `/app/jni/Android.mk`

Comment: @john Oh sorry my fault. I added the info you requested in the post update

Comment: So if I'm reading the makefile right (which isn't necessarily true) then the expectation is that you have this file `home/yolo/Workstation/Android/SDL/build/com.yolo.test/app/jni/SDL/include/SDL2/SDL.h` Do you have that file in that location?

Comment: I'm wondering if you followed step 2 of the instructions `Move or symlink this SDL directory into the "/app/jni" directory`

Comment: @john  ```/app/jni/SDL/inculde``` directory exists but the SDL2 folder inside it does not. there are a lot of SDL files (including SDL.h)  in  ```/app/jni/SDL/inculde``` but they aren't inside ```/app/jni/SDL/inculde/SDL2 ``` (this does not exist)

Comment: So I'm not really familiar with any of this, but my reading of that would be that your code uses SDL2, but this system does not have SDL2 installed. It's a version conflict in other words. Maybe someone more expert than me can confirm.

Comment: @john I have some progress. I created that ```/app/jni/SDL/inculde/SDL2``` folder and now it can find it. but it cant find ```SDL_image```

Comment: How did you create the `/app/jni/SDL` directory? As the instructions said, either move or symlink. I don't think you'll get very far creating files and directories by hand. You should start with an authentic SDL installation (which includes SDL2) and use that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245731/discussion-between-yolowex-and-john).